# How to call the same function twice without recursion

Tags: f#

```
let getValue number divisor =
    let firstNumber = int (System.Math.Floor((float) number / (float) divisor))
    let rest = number % divisor
    firstNumber, rest

let getNumeral value =
    match value with
    | (1, 1) -> "I"
    | (5, 1) -> "V"
    | (1, 2) -> "X"
    | (5, 2) -> "L"
    | (1, 3) -> "C"
    | (5, 3) -> "D"
    | (1, 4) -> "M"
    | (_,_) -> ""

let getStringRepresentation value =
    match value with
    | (1 , order) ->
        getNumeral (1, order)
    | (2, order) ->
        getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (1, order)
    | (3, order) ->
        getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (1, order)
    | (4, order) ->
        getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (5, order)
    | (5, order) ->
        getNumeral (5, order)
    | (6, order) ->
        getNumeral (5, order) + getNumeral (1, order)
    | (7, order) ->
        getNumeral (5, order) + getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (1, order)
    | (8, order) ->
        getNumeral (5, order) + getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (1, order)
    | (9, order) ->
        getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (1, order + 1)
    | (_, _) -> ""

let rec convertToRoman number =
    match number with
    | number when number >= 1000 && number < 4000 ->
        let value = getValue number 1000
        let rest = convertToRoman (snd value)
        let current = getStringRepresentation ((fst value), 4)
        current + rest
    | number when number >= 100 && number < 1000 ->
        let value = getValue number 100
        let rest = convertToRoman (snd value)
        let current = getStringRepresentation ((fst value), 3)
        current + rest
    | number when number >= 10 && number < 100 ->
        let value = getValue number 10
        let rest = convertToRoman (snd value)
        let current = getStringRepresentation ((fst value), 2)
        current + rest
    | number when number >= 1 && number < 10 ->
        let value = getValue number 1
        let rest = convertToRoman (snd value)
        let current = getStringRepresentation ((fst value), 1)
        current + rest
    | _ -> ""

printfn "%A" (convertToRoman 49)
```

I'm new to F# and the whole functional programming. Coming from C# I've decided to start with something easy. I'm trying to keep things simple for this time being. However, I have some trouble with calling some methods multiple times (getStringRepresentation) and I also think that the recursion could use some clean up, but I don't know how.

Any ideas how to call the function twice?

Comment: I don't understand your problem - you are quite obviously calling `getStringRepresentation` in multiple places and the code appears fine (if a little convoluted)- what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I think this is really stupid:
    | (8, order) ->
        getNumeral (5, order) + getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (1, order)

Comment: Why not `|(8,order) -> getNumeral(5,order)+getNumeral(3,order)`

Comment: Hard to help with "some trouble" with "some methods". Be specific with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can understand from the comments, what you really don't like is something like this:

```
getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (1, order) + getNumeral (1, order)
```

What you can do is to define another function which will let you repeat those calls:

```
let repeatOnes count order =
    let one _ = getNumeral (1, order)
    Seq.init count one |> Seq.reduce (+)
```

It uses `Seq.init` to initialize a sequence of function calls repeated `count` times. It then uses `Seq.reduce` to concatenate each of the resulting strings using the `+` operator. This enables you to write the above expression like this:

```
repeatOnes 3 order
```

---

As a first refactoring, then, you can replace all the occurances of `getNumeral (1, order)` like this:

```
let getStringRepresentation value =
    match value with
    | (1 , order) ->
        repeatOnes 1 order
    | (2, order) ->
        repeatOnes 2 order
    | (3, order) ->
        repeatOnes 3 order
    | (4, order) ->
        repeatOnes 1 order + getNumeral (5, order)
    | (5, order) ->
        getNumeral (5, order)
    | (6, order) ->
        getNumeral (5, order) + repeatOnes 1 order
    | (7, order) ->
        getNumeral (5, order) + repeatOnes 2 order
    | (8, order) ->
        getNumeral (5, order) + repeatOnes 3 order
    | (9, order) ->
        repeatOnes 1 order + getNumeral (1, order + 1)
    | (_, _) -> ""
```

---

However, you can now compact the patterns a bit:

```
let getStringRepresentation value =
    match value with
    | (count , order) when 1 <= count && count <= 3 ->
        repeatOnes count order
    | (4, order) ->
        repeatOnes 1 order + getNumeral (5, order)
    | (5, order) ->
        getNumeral (5, order)
    | (count, order) when 6 <= count && count <= 8 ->
        getNumeral (5, order) + repeatOnes (count - 5) order
    | (9, order) ->
        repeatOnes 1 order + getNumeral (1, order + 1)
    | (_, _) -> ""
```

---

Doing this in FSI:

```
> [1..50] |> List.map convertToRoman
```

produces this:

```
val it : string list =
  ["I"; "II"; "III"; "IV"; "V"; "VI"; "VII"; "VIII"; "IX"; "X"; "XI"; "XII";
   "XIII"; "XIV"; "XV"; "XVI"; "XVII"; "XVIII"; "XIX"; "XX"; "XXI"; "XXII";
   "XXIII"; "XXIV"; "XXV"; "XXVI"; "XXVII"; "XXVIII"; "XXIX"; "XXX"; "XXXI";
   "XXXII"; "XXXIII"; "XXXIV"; "XXXV"; "XXXVI"; "XXXVII"; "XXXVIII"; "XXXIX";
   "XL"; "XLI"; "XLII"; "XLIII"; "XLIV"; "XLV"; "XLVI"; "XLVII"; "XLVIII";
   "XLIX"; "L"]
```

so it seems to be still working.